# Flask: How can I get the parameter with the second query which is used for the function called with the first query?

Tags: python, flask

It's gonna be something like:

```py
@app.route('/phone_code', methods=['POST'])
def get_phone_code():
    return request.args.get('phone_code')

@app.route('/sign_in', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_in():
    with pyrogram.Client(
        phone_number=request.args.get('phone_number')
        phone_code=get_phone_code()) as client:
        pass
    return 'some specific server stuff'
```

So how can I get the code from `get_phone_code` using another Flask request?

UPD:
First I need to call `sign_in()` which runs `send_code()` function and generates `phone_code_hash` which is used to check the validity of the `phone_code` so `sign_in()` must be called before getting `phone_code`

Comment: Save that phone_code to database and query the database

Comment: @bigbounty first I need to call `sign_in()` which runs `send_code()` function and generates `phone_code_hash` which is used to check the validity of the `phone_code` so `sign_in()` must be called before getting `phone_code`